# Localhost is not a valid domain

Tags: python, web, flask, localhost

esta es mi primera vez realizando una pregunta en stackoverflow, comenzaré describiendo que estoy haciendo, luego el error obtenido, por ultimo lo que ya intente.

Hace poco utilizando Flask de una forma muy rudimentaria, cree una app web que utilizaba para mi mismo, para crearme notas y funciona perfecta, en esta app yo tenia que abrir un localhost:5003 para las rutas, y un puerto 5000 para la api, de ese modo lo hacia antes.

Cuestion que siguiendo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTYdcZ4aYz8&list=WL&index=7&t=782s
Utilizando programación orientada a objetos, he decidido re-crear el mini proyecto de notas, pero ahora cada vez que inicio el servidor obtengo el error mencionado.

Quiero destacar que tras finalizar el primer CRUD (El que controla las categorias) no me salia este error. Pero al crear el segundo CRUD (El que controla las notas) empezo a salir este error.

Ya he probado realizando cambios en el archivo config, cambiando el "SERVER_NAME" por "127.0.0.1:8080", probe quitar "SERVER_NAME" y utilizar "HOST" y "PORT" por separado.
Probe también alterando el archivo HOST de mi sistema:

La verdad ya no sé que intentar, adjuntare un link al proyecto en github por si lo quieren ver:
https://github.com/HakiShadow/Notas-2.0

Juro que ya no sé que mas intentar, no he encontrado nada efectivo en mis busquedas
Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: El link está caido. Por eso el código debe ir en la misma publicación (sin usar links a otros sitios). Y por supuesto ser un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DanteS. Es que no sabria que parte de todo el proyecto es la causante del problema, por eso adjunte todo, solo en caso que alguien quisiese verlo, tampoco sé porque esta caido...
Sobre lo que me dijo el bot, he dado todos los detalles que se me han venido a la mente, no sé que mas haga falta

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien mas le ocurre, lo solucione alterando el archivo host del sistema, lo deje asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente agregue una linea más
"127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain"

Luego en el archivo config, al SERVER_NAME lo puse así

SERVER_NAME = 'localhost.localdomain:8080'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]